# Creating Multiple users with Same password using ansible vault

Tags: ansible

I am having an issue with one of the tasks that needs to be performed.

We have to create five administrator accounts on Redhat Enterprise Linux with same password, and, also, three `l1admin` accounts with "same" password

Say all administrator accounts should have `Tch1l3@n` as password and all `Systemadmin` accounts should have `Ansible@123` as the password.

As the passwords in the Ansible playbook won't support plain text, I want the passwords to be encrypted and want to call them into the Ansible Playbook.

Can someone please help me on the same

I was trying with

```
ansible-vault encrypt_string Tch1l3@n
```

To get the encrypted value for the Password for `Tch1l3@n`

I am getting the following vault

```
!vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          32303631383436343830346436343331663739353033353237346431313038316539666431626530
          3665376537313934393136376236656337663934636236380a616362373866666139316434663866
          34623739353036613937636161656233663763393630303366396336326663326563323361363938
          3766633162633730340a613736333137343262643063346135373639303038626363343837383566
          3631
```

Then I am using the same in Ansible playbook with the following variable `Dev_password`

```yaml
---
- name: Creating multiple user (As of now I am creating Single user for Testing)
  hosts: localhost
  become_user: root
  become: true
  vars:
    Dev_password:  !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          32303631383436343830346436343331663739353033353237346431313038316539666431626530
          3665376537313934393136376236656337663934636236380a616362373866666139316434663866
          34623739353036613937636161656233663763393630303366396336326663326563323361363938
          3766633162633730340a613736333137343262643063346135373639303038626363343837383566
          3631
  tasks:
    - name: Creating the Users
      user:
        name: test_deva
        groups: wheel,admins
        password: "{{ Dev_password }}"
```

But I am getting the following message:

> [WARNING]: The input password appears not to have been hashed. The 'password' argument must be encrypted for this
> module to work properly.

And I am not able to login with the username and password.

Answer (score 2):

It's necessary to provide the `password` attribute with the sha512 password hash instead of a plain password. Use filter [password_hash](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#hashing-filters). For example

```yaml
    - name: Creating the Users
      user:
        name: test_deva
        groups: wheel,admins
        password: "{{ Dev_password|
                      password_hash }}"
```

This task is not idempotent because of the random salt used by the filter. If you want the solution to be idempotent use this

```yaml
    - name: Creating the Users
      user:
        name: test_deva
        groups: wheel,admins
        password: "{{ Dev_password|
                      password_hash('sha512', 65534|
                                              random(seed=inventory_hostname)|
                                              string) }}"
```